# I cannot understand the formula for between-imputation variance in multiple imputation

Tags: variance, standard-error, multiple-imputation

## Multiple Imputation (MI) for estimating desired a desired statistic but with missing data

Following [^Shafer](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0828282X20311119) (page 4), and [^Austin et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0828282X20311119) (section "Analyses in the M imputed data sets"), which give a primer on Rubin's book for MI.

Let

- $Y$ be our data, and break it into $Y_{obs}$ (observed/existing), $Y_{mis}$ (missing subset).
- $Q(Y)$ be the variable of interest, to be computed from our data.
- We need that $Q(Y)$ is a normal random variable for the following all to hold.

Method:

- Find a way to simulate $Y_{mis}$, and generate $\{Y_{mis}^{(i)}\}_{i = 1}^m$, $m$ samples.
- Compute $Q^i := Q(Y_{obs}, Y_{mis}^{(i)})$
- Compute $\bar{Q} := \sum_i Q^i / m$.  *This is our estimate!*

We can go further and get *t* statistic confidence intervals/hypothesis tests on how well $\bar{Q}$ approximates $Q$.

Required is the variance of $Q$:

0. Recall Total Variance formula: $var(Q) = E_Y( var(Q|Y) ) + var_Y( E(Q|Y))$.
1. We have to *know* the $U:= var(Q|Y)$'s formula.
2. Compute $U^{i}:= var(Q^i|Y^i)$
3. Estimate $E_Y( var(Q|Y) )$ by computing $\bar{U}:= \sum U^i/m$.

   - *This is the first term of the total variance formula*
   - This is called *average within-imputation variance*
4. $\bar{Q}:= \sum(Q^i)/m $, our estimate of $E(Q|Y)$ is already computed.
5. Compute $B:= (m-1)^{-1}\sum (Q^i-\bar{Q})^2$ to estimate $var( \bar{Q})$

   - This is called *between-imputation variance*
6. Finally, the desired estimate for $T:= Var(Q) = (1+(1/m))B + \bar{U}$

#### **Questions here!**

**Questions on step 5:**

- Isn't $B$ the sample variance for $\{Q^i\}$, which should estimate $var(Q(Y)|Y)$ which is just $U$?
- I think what we really want when we say $var_Y( E(Q|Y)$ is the *square of the sample error of the mean*, which is $B/m$. This follows [^StandardError](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_mean_versus_standard_deviation):

> The standard error [of the mean] is, by definition, the standard deviation of $ \bar{x}$ which is simply the square root of the variance:
> $\sigma_{\bar {x}} = \sqrt { \frac{\sigma^{2}}{n} } = \frac{\sigma}{ \sqrt{n}}$

- [^Austin et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0828282X20311119) go on to say

> When focusing on a single statistic, the Monte Carlo error can be computed as $\sqrt{B/M}$.

So this seems to confirm my logic above. If so, then is  *between-imputation variance* $B$ or $B/M$ or $(1+1/m)B$ ?

**Questions on step 6:**

- It seems to me that the total variance formula says $var(Q) = B/M + \bar{U}$. Am I right?
- If so, why does the formula in these papers multiply $B$ by $(1+1/m)$ and use  $var(Q) = B + B/m + \bar{U}$?

---

The paper's go on to say we can do Student T Test confidence intervals:

1. $(Q-\bar{Q})/T \sim $ Student T statistic with $\nu = (m-1)[1 + \frac{\bar{U}}{(1+(1/m))B}]^2$
2. This means $\bar{Q} \pm AT$ is a $k$ confidence interval if $A$ is the two-sided t-value at $(1-k,  \nu)$.

Question: If $m$ is sufficiently large (unsure, maybe 10K?) couldn't we use a z-score/Normal for our tests since Q(Y) normal?

**General Question**
Can you check my understanding of why we cannot just use $ \sum(Q^i - \bar{Q})^2/(m-1)$ as the estimate of variance of $Q$.  Because if $Y_{mis}$ doesn't effect $Q$ at all, then we'd get variance of 0 with this computation. We need $U$ to account for the variance that comes from $Q$ on $Y_{obs}$. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question as posed has an error as stated:

> 5. Compute $:=(−1)^{−1}\sum(^{i}−\bar{})^2$ to estimate $var(\bar{})$

should be
*Compute $:=(−1)^{−1}\sum(^{i}−\bar{})^2$ to estimate the sample variance of $\{Q^i\}$ (Not variance of $\bar{Q}$).* This error may be leading to some of the confusion. The goal is not to compute variance of $\bar{Q}$.

This answers the "Questions on step 5":

- for the first one is that yes $B$ is the sample variance for $\{Q^i\}$, which is different in general than $U=mean_i ( var(Q^{i}|Y^i))$.
- for the second question, yes $B/m$ is the empirical estimate for the variance of $\bar{Q}$ [see Wikipedia page on Standard Error of the Mean vs Standard Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_mean_versus_standard_deviation), but that is not what we are estimating.

Moving to the answers for the "Questions on step 6":

- it follows that the variance of $Q$ is $B + U$ from the total variance formula [see Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance)
- the answer by EdM shows that the empirical estimate of the total variance is $U + B + B/m$, which answers the second question on step 6.

Moving to the final question, looking at a t-table we see that for sufficiently large degrees of freedom ($\nu >= 1000$, say) it is the same as a z-table. From the computation for imputation t-test, for large $m$, this is the case. So the answer to the final question is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

The total variance formula you would like to use is based on an infinitely large number of imputations, with $\bar U_{\infty}$ and $B_{\infty}$ the within- and between-imputation variance. The estimate of the within-imputation variance $\bar U$ based on a finite number $m$ of imputations is unbiased, but there's a bias if you substitute the finite-imputation $B$ for $B_{\infty}$. Quoting Section 2.3.2 of van Buuren's [Flexible Imputation of Missing Data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-whyandwhen.html#sec:threesources):

> It is tempting to conclude that the total variance $T$ is equal to the sum of $\bar U$ and $B$, but that would be incorrect. We need to incorporate the fact that $\bar Q$ itself is estimated using finite $m$, and thus only approximates $Q_{\infty}$. Rubin shows that the contribution to the variance of this factor is systematic and equal to $B_{\infty}/m$.

With $B$ providing an approximation to $B_{\infty}$, you get the 3rd contribution to the total variance, $B/m$, that you are questioning.

Comment: This is a great link. thanks for this reference.